# File Exist even if there is no file in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a database in `Asset Folder` and i am trying to copy it to the app folder using below code. but it always `return false` (means file exists), I tried uninstalling the app and run the debug again but it always returns `false`

```
if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "mydatabase.db"))
{
    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(Application.Context.Assets.Open("mydatabase.db")))
    {
         using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "mydatabase.db"), FileMode.Create)))
         {
              byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
              int length = 0;
              while ((length = binaryReader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
              {
                  binaryWriter.Write(buffer, 0, length);
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the internal storage directory really doesn't have a file with that name?

You can check it by:

```
var appDir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
var files = Directory.GetFiles(appDir);
```

Or by using Java.IO;

```
var appDir = context.FilesDir();
var files = appDir.ListFiles();
```

and you can also use the output of above snippets for checking if the file exists.

Comment: i uninstalled the app and installed again and tried but still it shows the file exists.

Comment: You might want to check this: developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup